# How can I debug the following Go code, which tries to make a TCP connection to an IP address and port?

Tags: sockets, networking, go, tcp, network-programming

I am getting an IP address and port number from a Bittorrent tracker, for a specific torrent file. It represents a peer on the bittorrent network. I am trying to connect to the peer using this code. The connection always times out (getsockopt: operation timed out). I think I am missing something very fundamental here, because I tried the same code in python with the exact same result, operation timed out. It happens for every single peer IP address.

I downloaded this bittorrent client - https://github.com/jtakkala/tulva
which is able to connect to peers from my system using this type of code (Line 245, peer.go). I have also been able to use similar code for connecting to a tcp server running on localhost.

Edited details after JimB's comment and Kenny Grant's answer

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    raddr := net.TCPAddr{IP: []byte{}/*This byte slice contains the IP*/, Port: int(/*Port number here*/)}
    conn, err := net.DialTCP("tcp4", nil, &raddr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error while connecting", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Connected to ", raddr, conn)
}
```

Comment: The port simply isn't accepting connections. What do you want to debug? Your TCP address representation is strange -- what do you expect the leading 0s and 255s to do?

Comment: @JimB I was using the port as an example, because I didn't want to use placeholders. But it was misleading, so I have changed the code sample.

Comment: The IP and port aren't really relevant -- either you can connect or you can't, so I'm not sure what you want to debug here.

Comment: @JimB Since I was not able to connect, I assumed I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with a known good address, and you'll see your code works fine (with a 4 byte IPv4 address for SO say). Bittorrent peers are transient, so it probably just went away, if testing you should use your own IPs that you know are stable.

```
raddr := net.TCPAddr{IP: net.IPv4(151, 101, 1, 69), Port: int(80)}
...
-> Connected to  {151.101.1.69 80 }
```

if you're trying to connect to 187.41.59.238:10442, as jimb says, it's not available. For IPs, see the docs:

https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/golang/go@9fd359a29a8cc55ed665542d2a3fe9fef8baaa7d/-/blob/src/net/ip.go#L32:6-32:8

Comment: Thanks for responding. I was actually just using that address as an example, I wanted the code to be syntactically correct. I realize now that it was misleading, and have updated the question. I'm getting a list of peers from the tracker and am trying to contact them all, and repeat the process when I'm out of peers. Every peer connection times out. I'll take your advice and try this code for a non localhost IP:Port combo which I know to be stable.

Comment: Thanks again for introducing me to sourcegraph by the way, it looks like a really helpful tool.